# How to create a centered <div> which automatically shrinks if it doesn't fit within the viewport?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'd like to have my HTML5 video box both vertically and horizontally centered within a <div> with fixed width. The tricky thing is, that I want the video to shrink to fit completely inside the viewport, when the viewport is in either height or width smaller than the video.

And of course I would like to accomplish the resizing without JavaScript. I am fine, if older browsers fail to do the resizing.

I actually found a quite nice solution (see code below). However I have a quite bad feeling with it, because the WebKit-based browsers have an other understanding of some CSS than IE 11, 10 & 9 (while FireFox is here above both)

To achieve the desired result I set max-width of the video and the outer container (#parent) to 100%.

However this does not work with Internet Explorer 11, 10 & 9. Looks like IE is interpreting `#parent video {max-width:100%}` as 100% of the video and not of the containing block. As a result the video juts out of it's container and does not resize. However IE is behaving fine if I set `#parent video {width:100%}`.

The WebKit-based browsers (Safari, Chrome, new Opera) on the other hand need `#parent video {width:auto}`. Otherwise they behave not nice, if a too small vertical size of the view-port wants the video to shrink. (In my example you will see blue background, which should be covered completely by the video.)

So my questions are:

- What do the standard say: Is WebKit or IE right? Or is FireFox and    Edge right, which are fine with either (or both) max-width and/or width set to 100%?
- Is my code & goal maybe out of that, what is possible with CSS and works just by chance?
- Do you know a better solution to accomplish this self-shrinking video?

Here is my "solution":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
  </script>

  <style>
  #parent{
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;  top: 0;
    height: 100%;  width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;  justify-content:center;
  }
  #parent > div {
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid white;
    background-color:blue;
    margin: 30px;
  }
  #parent video {
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; /* needed by IE and older browsers (e.g. FireFox 21) */
  }
  @supports(display:flex){ /* all newer browser (but not IE 11 & IE 10, which have flex but not @supports) */
    #parent video {
    width: auto; /* needed by Chrome, Safari and new Opera (while FireFox and Edge are also fine with width:100%) */
    }
  }
  #parent div#close {
    position: absolute;
    right: -17px;  top: -17px;  width: 20px; height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;  border-radius: 100%;  background-color: white;
  }


  /* additional styling for older browsers not supporting flexbox */
  #parent {
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
  #parent::after {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    content:" ";
    height:100%; width:0;
  }
  #parent > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
  html[data-useragent*='Presto'] #parent,
  html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] #parent {
    display:block; /* IE10 and old Opera have a broken flexbox implementation */
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="parent">
    <div id="inner">
      <video controls>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
      </video>
      <div id="close">X<div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6vu42zxr

Comment: So In IE and Chrome the same CSS is working differently right?

Comment: That is correct: IE needs `#parent video {width:100%}`, while Chrome/Safari/Opera need `#parent video {width:auto}`, while FireFox and Edge can go with both

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you are having CSS issue for IE and Webkit browsers. Why dont you right separate CSS for IE browser? Which will target IE only browser. So that you will have separate CSS for IE and chrome and other browsers.

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE only CSS:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE Browser:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY Browser:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY Browser:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and LOWER Browser:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Why to use conditional stylesheets?

- Keep your code hack-free and valid.
- Keep your main stylesheet clean.
- Easy to edit IE only CSS and maintain.
- And remember, these conditional tags you could use to load JavaScript, or anything related to IE browser.

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but do you know that conditional comments do no longer work in IE10 and newer? (So I could only use them if I force IE10 and IE11 to render my page in IE9 compatibility mode, what I don't like to do) Furthermore I don't need to know how to provide different CSS for different browsers (there are several techniques available). I'd like to know if my code is solid. So **which CSS is correct** according to the spec? Or can I accomplish the same goal without the need for different CSS for different browsers?